# Am I losing scope within IF statements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is my `completeText` variable losing its scope within the `if` statements? If `completeText` is used outside the statements it works, which leads me to believe I need to declare something prior to using it as a label within the statement.

```
public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool isClicked = false;
        string cdrw = "CD-RW";
        public string txt;
        public string completeText = "";
        public GameObject cdrwModel;
        public StreamReader reader = null;
        public FileInfo theSourceFile = null;

    public void Start()
    {
        theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
        if (theSourceFile != null && theSourceFile.Exists)
            reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
        if (reader == null)
        {
        Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
        }
        else 
        {
           while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
                Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
                completeText += txt;
            }
         }
      }

      public void OnMouseEnter() {
          isClicked = true;
          completeText += txt;
      }

      public void OnGUI() {
      if ((isClicked) && (cdrwModel)){

            GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);

            }
       }
```

Comment: Why do you think its losing scope?

Comment: Because when I put it at the beginning of OnGUI() it works perfectly! It's only when I bring it into the IF statements that nothing appears

Comment: Are you certain that the body of the if statement is executed?

Comment: Yes the "Press <Tab> for more information appears as I hover over the cdrw model - I have a feeling its to do with my parenthesis and their placement

Comment: There's an additional if statement around the use of `completeText`. The fact that "Press <TAB>" is displayed doesn't give you the whole story.

Comment: This is where I mainly focus on and if I set the variable prior like this it will work - it is just the variable I need from a text file not carrying over

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                completeText = "Hello";
                GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);

            }

Comment: I don't have Unity3d, so I'm not sure if there's something going on there, but I was just wondering if there are any background threads causing it to be out of scope for the thread at which you're breaking?  I.e. ahead of your IF statement, you break in thread 1 and see the value.  In the IF statement, you don't on break because when the condition is true a different thread is in progress?  You could test this by making the variable static.  If you see the value, you'll know it's a threading issue for sure.

Comment: THAT WORKED! I made it static and it worked! :D So you think that means there is an issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaindreas: Yeah, now what this says is that your class is not thread-safe for however it's being used.  Here's a link to some really good info on making classes/variables thread-safe:  http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @bjhuffine Might be worth moving your suggestions in the comments into an answer - this way, the OP can accept it and we can consider this question solved.

Comment: @Serlite thanks for the heads up. :) Added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Unity3d, so I'm not sure if there's something going on there, but I was just wondering if there are any background threads causing it to be out of scope for the thread at which you're breaking? I.e. ahead of your IF statement, you break in thread 1 and see the value. In the IF statement, you don't on break because when the condition is true a different thread is in progress? You could test this by making the variable static. If you see the value, you'll know it's a threading issue for sure.

With a threading issue, you're class will need to be more tolerant to multiple threads accessing its properties without getting out of sync causing errant decisions.  More information on this can be found at: http://www.albahari.com/threading/