# the onclick button function does not seem to call the randommath function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, buttonclick

i am trying to create the freaking math app using unity 3d for learning purpose.
i could not see the random math function is being called in the below sourcecode.

when i click the play button i could get random numbers, but once i click the true button or the false button, i dont see the randommath function being called.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameControllerScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text MathText;
    public Text ResultText;

    private int rightNumber;
    private int leftNumber;
    private int TrueResultNumber;
    private int FalseResultNumber;

    void Start()
    {
        RandomMath ();
    }

    void RandomMath()
    {
        rightNumber = Random.Range (0, 10);
        leftNumber = Random.Range (0, 10);

        int mOperator = Random.Range (0,2);
        switch (mOperator) {
        case 0:
            TrueResultNumber = leftNumber + rightNumber;
            MathText.text = leftNumber.ToString () + "+" + rightNumber.ToString ();
            FalseResultNumber = TrueResultNumber + Random.Range (-2, 2);
            ResultText.text = "=" + FalseResultNumber.ToString ();
            break;
        case 1:
            TrueResultNumber = leftNumber + rightNumber;
            MathText.text = leftNumber.ToString () + "-" + rightNumber.ToString ();
            FalseResultNumber = TrueResultNumber + Random.Range (-2, 2);
            ResultText.text = "=" + FalseResultNumber.ToString ();
            break;
        case 2:
            TrueResultNumber = leftNumber + rightNumber;
            MathText.text = leftNumber.ToString () + "*" + rightNumber.ToString ();
            FalseResultNumber = TrueResultNumber + Random.Range (-2, 2);
            ResultText.text = "=" + FalseResultNumber.ToString ();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    public void OnTrueButtonClick()
    {
        if (TrueResultNumber == FalseResultNumber) {
            RandomMath();

        } 
        else {
        }
    }
    public void OnFalseButtonClick()
    {

        if (TrueResultNumber != FalseResultNumber) {
            RandomMath();
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set up the click event in the inspector. if the above script is on a game object try the following

click on your button in the inspector click the + sign to add a click event. 
drag the object with the script to the slot and make sure editor and runtime is selected.
select the function GameControllerScript.OnFalseButtonClick

repeat on the other button but use OnTrueButtonClick

it should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign the action for the button?

The name of your methods doesn't have any relationship with the name of the buttons, so you have to assign the related method by your own.

See this video, 5:35 ;)

https://youtu.be/kQ2Qc_0MIyI?t=335

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Unity3d, but there was someone on this forum once who found that their variables were out of scope causing certain operations to not occur.  It turned out that this framework evidently utilizes multiple threads.  They were able to determine this by making the class-level variables static.  That exposes the same variables to all threads.  I just noticed that your OnTrueButtonClick() operation has conditions using class-level variables that are non-static as well.  That was at [Am I losing scope within IF statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341416/am-i-losing-scope-within-if-statements)

It would be worth a shot.